# java program to get the cpu and memory info of the system

Tags: java

I'm using this code to get some values

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
for (Method method : operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    method.setAccessible(true);
    if (method.getName().startsWith("get") 
        && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
        Object value;
        try {
            value = method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            value = e;
        } // try
        System.out.println("\n \t ");
        System.out.println( method.getName() +     " = "    + value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
getFreeSwapSpaceSize = 413728768

getProcessCpuLoad = -1.0

getProcessCpuTime = 1029606600

getSystemCpuLoad = 0.31576507895572437

getCommittedVirtualMemorySize = 48242688

getFreePhysicalMemorySize = 207011840

getTotalPhysicalMemorySize = 2147483647

getTotalSwapSpaceSize = 4294967295
```

But I want to get each of this data separately, the above output values are stored in `value` and its getting stored in that single object. I want to use it in swings so that in each button click I get the above values separately. As of now in a single button click I get all the above information together but I want it to be separately, For eg: total physical memory separately, then the System CPU Load etc...

How can I modify the above program so that I can store each value separately?

Comment: I'm guessing that code isn't yours? You probably want to replace the for-loop alltogether, and fetch your specific information in a similar way. If you want to assume a certain order you can keep the loop, and simply store each value fetched in some list, for example.

Comment: It sounds like you want the Swing button to pass through the name of what value you want. So, for example, if the button should display Free Swap Space Size, then it should send through method name = "FreeSwapSpaceSize" and then your code calls the get method `getFreeSwapSpaceSize()`. And then your Swing UI has several buttons, one for each value you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

For each Button that you are going to put in the UI create them as

```
   Button b1 = new Button();
   b1.setActionCommand("getTotalSwapSpace");
   b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
            try {
                Method method = operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getTotalSwapSpaceSize", null);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean, new Object[]{});
                System.out.println(" Value = " + value);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Display the value that is returned. Have changed the original code, try this..

Comment: @:Pradyumna Mohapatra errors are showing near "getCommandName" and "getDeclaredMethod near object[]" that it is undefined. I tried all possible ways ..I'm not getting the output.. can u please explain me...

Answer (score 0):

For CPU use OperatingSystemMXBean class

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
int availableProcessors = operatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors();
long prevUpTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
long prevProcessCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
double cpuUsage;
try
{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch (Exception ignored) { }

operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long upTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
long processCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
long elapsedCpu = processCpuTime - prevProcessCpuTime;
long elapsedTime = upTime - prevUpTime;

cpuUsage = Math.min(99F, elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime * 10000F * availableProcessors));
System.out.println("Java CPU: " + cpuUsage);
```

For memory use Runtime class in java.lang.management

```
long total = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long used = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
        - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Comment: @:ravi ranjan    thank u for the help.. but in the above code for the memory use ,it gives the memory use of the JVM, but I want to get the total physical memory of the system

Comment: it is all OS dependent for windows/linux first search the command for getting RAM size. Now execute the command using java. For window it is "wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory" use the following for running cmd commands `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", query));`  where querty is command